# newrelic application name changed but old application can't be remove

Tags: newrelic

I created in NewRelic a application name

After few hours I changed the application name

Now old application can't be removed, it's still mark as green in the UI

How can I mark it grey/remove the old application name?

- This is also true after 1 day (not a timing issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must restart application.
Only after restart the old application name can be removed